# How to reuse a HTML div block to show different menus

Tags: javascript, json

First of all I am not a Javascript expert and I have only started. So here is the problem:
I have a page and a menu, when clicking on one of the menu items a second menu pops up with some items in it. The pop up menu is based on a div that has a `<ul>` within it.
What I am thinking is to store all needed information for each menu item in separate json files and then on clicking the menu item the json file is read and a div block is created with the correct information.

The question is, does this take a lot of time for the div to be created and then used?, also what happens to the created div when the popup is closed.

Also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are describing Model View Controller pattern. You've got a json with the model, a template with the view and you need a file to control the view with the model. You can use a template system to make the task easy. Take a look to handlebars or underscore.js: http://handlebarsjs.com/ | http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rimiduhoke/edit?html,css,js,output As you can see, the time hide/show a simple `div` is not long (after the browser's animation of the closing select menu, it essentially no time at all. As for what happens to it, that's a matter of how you "hide/show" it. you can use `display` as I've done, which removes visibility for the user but still keeps it on the DOM, or you may want to remove it from the DOM completely. It's up to you based on your given situation.

Comment: Thank you Marcos, handlebars was exactly what I was looking for.